# Aggregate function with analytic function over partition on teradata- elected non-aggregated values must be part of the associated group

Tags: sql, teradata, partition

I have to count number of status changes but only if the time difference from one status to another is less then 30 minutes. In my database i have current time and previous time column i made by using over partition. Here is my query but I am getting the error:
"Selected non-aggregated values must be part of the associated group".
Could anyone help ?

```
select col1, col2,
    MAX(creation_dt_utc) OVER(PARTITION BY col1,col2,col3 ORDER BY creation_dt ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS previous_creation_dt,
    (creation_dt - prev_creation_dt) DAY(4) TO SECOND(6) as time_difference,
    EXTRACT(DAY FROM time_difference) * 24*60 + EXTRACT(HOUR FROM time_difference) * 60 + EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM time_difference) AS Total_Minutes
    SUM(
        CASE WHEN status_previous='Test1'
                and status_current='Test2' THEN 1

            ELSE    

                CASE WHEN status_previous='Test3'
                    and status_current='Test2' THEN 1                           
            ELSE
                CASE WHEN status_previous='Test4'
                    and status_current='Test2' THEN 1                       
                ELSE 0
                END
            END
        END
    ) AS "Total_Change"
from myTable
qualify Total_Minutes<30
where EXTRACT(YEAR from year_column)='2017';
```

[image]

Comment: Aren't you missing the `group by col1, col2` at the end? However, there are more problems with your SQL. Try to post sample input and expected output for this input.

Comment: yes, sorry. I added group by col1, col2, but i am still having the same error: "Selected non-aggregated values must be part of the associated group"

Comment: What is your expected result based on the current Select without the SUM?

Comment: My expected result should be total number of changes where the time difference from one status to another is less then 30 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that QUALIFY should be after the WHERE clause.

And for a previous value, I assume LAG would be more fitting than a MAX.

And those nested `CASE` can be written as 1 `CASE`. 
Because once a `WHEN` condition is met, it won't check the other WHEN conditions after it.

Since a normal SUM is used, there should be a GROUP BY.

```
SELECT col1, col2,
 COUNT(*) AS Total,
 SUM(TimeDiffMinutes) AS Total_Minutes,
 SUM(CASE WHEN StatusChanged = 1 THEN TimeDiffMinutes ELSE 0 END) AS Total_Minutes_Change,
 COUNT(CASE WHEN StatusChanged = 1 THEN 1 END) AS Total_Change
FROM
(
  SELECT col1, col2, col3, creation_dt,
  (CASE 
   WHEN status_previous='Test1' and status_current='Test2' THEN 1
   WHEN status_previous='Test3' and status_current='Test2' THEN 1   
   WHEN status_previous='Test4' and status_current='Test2' THEN 1
   ELSE 0
   END) AS StatusChanged,
  LAG(creation_dt) OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2, col3 ORDER BY creation_dt) AS prev_creation_dt,
  (creation_dt - prev_creation_dt) DAY(4) TO SECOND(6) AS time_difference,
  EXTRACT(DAY FROM time_difference)*(24*60) + EXTRACT(HOUR FROM time_difference)*60 + EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM time_difference) AS TimeDiffMinutes
  FROM myTable  
  WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR from year_column) = '2017'
  QUALIFY (creation_dt - prev_creation_dt) day(4) to second(6) < interval '30' minute
) q
GROUP BY col1, col2
ORDER BY col1, col2
```

Comment: Logically the QUALIFY is done after WHERE/GROUP BY/HAVING, but Teradata's parser is (way too) flexible and doesn't care about the order of keywords after SELECT :-)  And LAG has been aded lately, in TD16.10, the OP might run an older version...

Comment: But it still should be put after it ;)  Because I think that conditions on windows functions are typically evaluated after WHERE and HAVING conditions. And ok, don't know his version. Oh well, if his version doesn't have LAG then he still has the MAX.

Comment: Of course, it's totally confusing when you see a Select and the keywords are in the wrong order :-)

Answer (score 1):

Analytic funtions are processed after aggregation (where-from-group by-having-olap-qualify-order by), thus you can't apply an aggregate on the result of an OVER, you mst nest it in a Derived Tabe or a Common Table Expression:

```
SELECT
   Sum(
       CASE WHEN (status_previous='Test1' AND status_current='Test2')
              OR (status_previous='Test3' AND status_current='Test2')
              OR (status_previous='Test4' AND status_current='Test2')
            THEN 1                       
            ELSE 0
       END) AS "Total_Change"
FROM
 (
   SELECT col1, col2,
       Max(creation_dt_utc)
       Over(PARTITION BY col1,col2,col3
            ORDER BY creation_dt
            ROWS BETWEEN 1 Preceding AND 1 Preceding) AS previous_creation_dt,

       (creation_dt - prev_creation_dt) DAY(4) TO SECOND(6) AS time_difference,

       Extract(DAY From time_difference) * 24*60 + Extract(HOUR From time_difference) * 60 + Extract(MINUTE From time_difference) AS Total_Minutes

   FROM myTable
   WHERE Extract(YEAR From year_column)=2017 -- the result of EXTRACT is an INTEGER, not a string
   QUALIFY Total_Minutes<30
 ) AS dt
```

But as you only want a count you could move the CASE into QUALIFY:

```
SELECT Count(*) AS "Total_Change"
FROM
 (
   SELECT col1, col2,
       Max(creation_dt_utc)
       Over(PARTITION BY col1,col2,col3
            ORDER BY creation_dt
            ROWS BETWEEN 1 Preceding AND 1 Preceding) AS previous_creation_dt,

       (creation_dt - prev_creation_dt) DAY(4) TO SECOND(6) AS time_difference,

       Extract(DAY From time_difference) * 24*60 + Extract(HOUR From time_difference) * 60 + Extract(MINUTE From time_difference) AS Total_Minutes

   FROM myTable
   WHERE Extract(YEAR From year_column)=2017 -- the result of EXTRACT is an INTEGER, not a string
   QUALIFY Total_Minutes<30
       AND (   (status_previous='Test1' AND status_current='Test2')
            OR (status_previous='Test3' AND status_current='Test2')
            OR (status_previous='Test4' AND status_current='Test2')
           )
 ) AS dt
```

Edit:

The CASE logic can be further simplified to:

```
CASE WHEN status_current='Test2' and status_previous IN ('Test1','Test3','Test4')
     THEN 1                       
     ELSE 0
END
```

or maybe

```
CASE WHEN status_current='Test2' and status_previous <>'Test2'
     THEN 1                       
     ELSE 0
END
```

Comment: thank you very much for sharing this edited example :)